# Rhino: How to allow redeclaration of 'NaN' variable?

Tags: javascript, rhino

Using Rhino javascript interpretor 17R4,

i gets an exception "TypeError: redeclaration of const NaN."

```
     Context context = Context.enter();
     ScriptableObject scope = context.initStandardObjects();
     context.setLanguageVersion(180);
     context.evaluateString(scope, "var NaN=0x7ff0000000000001;", "", 1, null);// <== Type Error
```

While, Standard brower, such as IE and Chrome allows local variable. "var NaN=42;alert(NaN);" 
(See zerkms's provided example "http://jsfiddle.net/UCN2n/")

Is there way to declare local variable 'NaN'?

Answer (score 0):

No, [`NaN` is a constant](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.23) that cannot be redeclared. While Chrome may not throw an exception, it also doesn't allow you to change the definition of `NaN`:

[image: Chrome doesn't allow you to change the definition of <code>NaN</code>]

Comment: I can't explain that one, but you really shouldn't be redeclaring the language-defined constant `NaN`; @Yone you have a practical reason for wanting to do so? Maybe there's another way to arrive at your desired result.

Comment: I'm not an OP. I just made a note that your answer is not correct. By saying "not correct" I literally mean it - the ECMAScript reference proves nothing. There is a keyword with `NaN` name. So what? What do you mean by "constant"?

Comment: I personally dislike using 'NaN' also... but in reality, there is some scripts using var NaN=....in the web (see  "http://www.html5haven.com/sokobanpalace/html5game/SokobanPalace.js?USNYB=1156996610"). My rhino compiler gives up compile these scripts entirely. Is there any way to make rhino to ignore like Chrome?

Comment: @Yone - presumably, you could alter the source-code for Rhino and recompile it, but it seems like trying to use a sledge-hammer to break a peanut that's in your way, when you could just walk around the peanut.